# RecyclerView and ListView appearing offset on certain devices -- possible graphical glitch

Tags: android

I've received a bug report from a user that's quite confusing. The user reports that two lists in the app are broken. Firstly, the lists appear out of place with both a vertical and horizontal offset, with the vertical offset being greater (see picture) and secondly, when they tap on an item in the list, it opens a different item to the one they clicked. Drag-to-reorder also captures a list item further down than where they pressed. As the lists are appearing lower down than they should, my theory is that some sort of graphical glitch is showing the list out of place, but still registering and acting upon touch events as though the list were in the correct place -- resulting in the 'wrong item' part of the problem. However I'm at a loss as to what could cause a bug like this -- it's more than a layout issue because the system seems to be confused about where the list is as well! Photo below (note that cirular blob in bottom corner is just a Facebook Messenger chat head)

The bug appears on a Sony F3311 and Blu Diamond M, both running Android 6.0 / API 23, but not a Nexus 7 running Android 6.0.1. We've not encountered it on any other emulators or devices, right up to a Pixel 4a.

**Update:** the issue seems to be caused by using a fading edge on the lists (a ListView in one case, a RecyclerView in the other.) Removing this fixes this, but I can't work out why exactly it's happening, or even what devices attributes cause it.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more info if its Device or ROM specific issue and is the list working fine on other device

Comment: @AkashPal have done, thanks

Comment: sure will look into it as it seems to be gpu based problem similar to one i faced